# Analyzing Part of a String

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C and I have an assignment where I have to build a dictionary (Linked List in a way). Basically the user inputs several words,year and their definition this:

Example:

```
love_#_2004_#_LOVING
trade_#_2001_#_INVEST
etc...
```

And basically I need a function to scan the definition (Ex: INVEST)
and gives me the word trade.

If the definition is related to more than only one word to give me back all the words it relates to.

What sort of a function do I need to scan these strings?

Comment: `strstr()` to find a substring, `strtok_r()` to split a string on delimiters.

Comment: First you have to find what data structure you will use.

Comment: We are not here to help you with your assignments, you will need to show you tried and couldn't solve some issue, not solve it for you

Comment: I only wanted ideas on how should i do it. I never asked you to solve it. You can see on the post i put

Answer (score 1):

If the word you search is always the last one and the formatting is always the same, then use [`strtok`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Finding-Tokens-in-a-String.html) with `_` and copy the last entry, which holds the string you are looking for.